# How to allow exec node to only run when a specific string is passed through it?

Tags: node-red

I understand that I may not grasp how these nodes actually work, and that's ok. I like learning. But I am curious as to if there is a way to set up an exec node so that only a specific string or parameter will work when passed through? I am new to all this stuff so please bear with me on that. If JS or python function node is needed I can also learn those, but don't fully understand how those work yet either.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `exec` node has no built in filtering, it will run on any input message.

If you want to make running the `exec` node conditional then you will need to control which messages get passed to the `exec` node. There are multiple ways you can do this:

- The `switch` node is specifically designed to do flow control, it can be used to test msg properties and then decide if a msg should be output from a specific port on the switch node.
- You can write a `function` node to run what ever tests you want on an incoming msg and decide if the msg object should be forwarded.

Unfortunately without knowing exactly what you want to compare to what I can't really give any more details.

Comment: ah ok I see. Thank for the help!